# Is it possible to limit resources assigned to a Spark session?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm launching pySpark sessions with the following code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I've noticed that if a notebook is running a pySpark query, and a second notebook tries to start a Spark session, the second Spark session will not start until the first one has finished (i.e. the first session is taking all the resources).

Is there some way to limit the resources of a Spark session or parallelize multiple sessions somehow?

Comment: setting spark.driver.cores / spark.executor.cores ?

Comment: How? Can you post the code?

Comment: I think you can set it in $SPARK_HOME/spark-defaults.conf - put the line `spark.driver.cores 1`in that file

Comment: you dont have enough of resources to run multiple sessions. Beef up your instance. Maybe post the system specs where you're running this on.